# Change size textview in fragment view pager from button in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app I have a activity.
My activity

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Rlayout_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnUp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layout_btn_back"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btup" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDown"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnUp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btdown" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Rlayout_top" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in my fragment view Pager I have a scroll view, in scroll view I have a few pictures and text.
Now I want when click button in activity I can change size of textview in scroll view
How i do?I was looking for a solution and found some reviews say should use the interface, but I still do not get it
Please help me!
Thank all

Comment: Can you give me full code so that i can try it at my place

Comment: Can you  leave email? i will send it for you

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.getLayoutParams.Height = pixels;
```

Comment: I do not quite get it

Comment: define your textView in your fragment:
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
then write the above line

Comment: I want when set onclick listener button in activity then text in fragment change size. Your method can solve it?

Comment: try this.
textView = viewPager.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.textView);